# SSMS 2014 (and 2012) CTRL+TAB requires pressing enter

Tags: ssms

Sometime last week my CTRL+TAB behavior changed.  I used to hit CTRL+TAB, release, then I would be in my previous document tab.  Now I hit CTRL+TAB, release, and the nav window is still open requiring me to hit enter.

I have tried restarting ssms and rebooting several times.  This is an issue in both SSMS 2012 and 2014.  It is *not* an issue in Visual Studio (2010 and 2013).

In all VS 2010/2013 and SSMS 2012/2014 the hotkey `Ctrl+Tab (Global)` is set to `Window.NextDocumentWindowNav`.  Though I have tried modifying it then putting it back.

[image]

CTRL+F6 works the same as it always has.

Is there a way to get the CTRL+TAB behavior back?

Comment: Have you installed any new software recently that perhaps changes the way dialog windows work?  Perhaps some multi-monitor management software or something like that?  Maybe a new video driver, perhaps?

Comment: My fresh install of SQL Server Management Studio 2012 does *not* exhibit the behavior you mention.

Comment: Maybe some type of accessibility feature that you may have accidentally enabled in Windows? Also, is this occurring in a Remote Desktop session? The Remote Desktop client sometimes does funny things to certain "special" windows keys like AltGr and Alt+Tab, though I haven't experienced your particular issue before..

Comment: @MaxVernon I don't recall installing anything; but that is most likely the culprit.

Comment: @DanielHutmacher The behavior only exists in SSMS and works correctly in Visual Studio.  It's unlikely a hotkey setting of that sort.  Though there may be a context-sensitive setting somewhere.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem in SSMS for SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score -1):

To fix this issue: Tools \ Options \ Keyboard.  Bring up the command in the "Show commands containing:" list.  Then in the "Press shortcut keys:" text box press CTRL+Tab and click Assign.  This will re-assign the command back to itself, but fixed the "sticky" window.  Just had the same issue. Hope this helps.

[image: Re-assign the command]

Comment: Didn't work for me :(

Comment: Didn't work for me either.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: I don't see any help in telling OP to do what he already stated he tried and didn't work. It seems whatever problem you had was different.